# Inconsistent results of NumPy memory allocation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, out-of-memory, allocation

This Python 3.11 script on Ubuntu 22.04 with about 16.4GB memory available (no swap file):

```
import numpy as np, psutil

print(f'{psutil.virtual_memory().available:,}')

try:
  a = np.empty((100_000_000_000), dtype='u1')  # variant A
  # a = np.empty((30_000_000_000), dtype='u1')  # variant B
  # a = np.ones((30_000_000_000), dtype='u1')  # variant C
  print(f'{a.size:,}')
except RuntimeError as e:
  print(e)

print('Done')
```

produces unexpected inconsistent results.

Variant A produces an exception as expected:

```
16,436,457,472
...
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 93.1 GiB for an array with shape (100000000000,) and data type uint8
```

Variant B unexpectedly allocates an array larger than available memory:

```
16,335,642,624
30,000,000,000
Done
```

Variant C fails silently:

```
16,337,346,560
```

Can someone explain variant B and C behavior?

Comment: Related: [Linux kernel: Role of zero page allocation at paging_init time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35550384/11082165). When numpy "allocates" `30_000_000_000` uninitialized bytes, it doesn't actually allocate that much physical memory. Instead, you get a whole bunch of zero pages, which don't get fulfilled by physical pages until you actually write to them. That's why variant B "works" and doesn't use any significant memory, while variant C results in actual memory allocation gets reaped by the OOM killer

Comment: @Brian61354270 Is there a way to make variant C throw an exception?

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not aware of how to do that. In the extreme case you can look into customizing [numpy's memory management](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/data_memory.html) and/or [Python's memory management](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html#memoryoverview).

Comment: `psutil.virtual_memory().available` seems to return the amount of available RAM on my machine but a program can use more than that. First, memory can be compressed on mainstream systems (it is actually by default on Windows), then the swap file/storage can be used to store part of the RAM so you can typically allocate and fill significantly more than that. Not to mention the available amount of RAM change dynamically an can be lower just after an allocation because of any running (background) process. Strategy based on the available RAM are doomed to fail.

Comment: If you want your program not to crash lately because of that, you need to allocate (most) and fill data during the initialisation of your program. Note that `np.full` should fill the target array. It is slower but there is not alternative : the kernel cannot reserve page without filling them for security reasons. You can disable this security on Linux in the kernel parameter but this is (very) dangerous in most case (the only use-case where it is OK is a computing machine not connected to internet running only non-critical computations and with a limited user access).

Comment: If you wish to tune the way allocations works, then you can overwrite the libc malloc/realloc/free functions using `LD_PRELOAD` on Linux. You can for example preallocate a big chunk and fill it at startup time so not to pay any overhead later and avoid the not-enough memory issue. TCMalloc does something like this for example (used by Google).